# How to parse nested tags in iPhone sdk?

Tags: ios, ios4, tags, xml-parsing

I have an xml file which has the following tags:

```
<records>
    <record>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <a1>A</a1>
    <a2>ABC</a2>
    <a3>ABCDE</a3>
    <a4>12345</a4>
    <a5>123456</a5>
    </record>
</records>
```

Using xml parsing, I am able to parse the `<record>` along with the tags in it. I want to parse this data with the tags contained inside the `<record>`, ie, I want to display the data with the tags that are contained inside the `<record>`, such as `<a1>` or `<a2>`.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You say you're able to parse it so what's the exact problem?  What parser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what parser are you using. Since you don't specified your answer a bit,  I can advise you to use this one:

- http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html

Being using in some projects and never failed me. If you need help, just let me know.

Comment: okay leave the nested parsing. Can you please help me what to do if i want to filter some data according to a search request sent? i mean, in the above xml tags,consideering there isa a big xml file with same data in <a1> tag, i am able to parse the tags very perfectly. But now, i want to display only the data, which has A data in it,ie, i want to display only that record, that has a data A in <a1> tag. So how to do that?

Comment: Humm. You can try to query the XML, or you can create a structure with your XML, for instance an array with objects of the type record.